# Multiple Reference Navigation properties to same table

Tags: entity-framework-core, relational-database, navigation-properties

In a EF Core model there are two classes, Company and Employee. 1 Company can have multiple Employees. I am wondering if I can add to reference navigation properties (collection of employees with different roles, i.e. manager role) referencing the same employees table and have EF Core figure out which employees to display in what property, depending on a property of the employee class (isManager, true/false).

See below, would this be possible?

```cs
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.empty;
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Minions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Managers { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {
        Minions = new HashSet<Employee>();
        Managers = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.empty;
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; } = null!;
    public bool IsManager { get; set; }
}
```

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "MonkeyBizz Inc." |

| Id | Name | CompanyId | IsManager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "John Doe" | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | "Jane Doe" | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | "Skippy the Magnificent" | 1 | 1 |

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "MonkeyBizz Inc.",
    "minions": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "John Doe", "companyId": 1, "isManager": false },
        { "id": 2, "name": "Jane Doe", "companyId": 1, "isManager": false }
    ],
    "managers": [
        { "id": 3, "name": "Skippy the Magnificent", "companyId": 1, "isManager": true }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You could mimic this using a couple of methods. One would be to create views for minions and managers. But I would not recommend doing that. Instead, get your data and present it to the consumer in a view model of some kind where you split up the employees into groups.

Comment: Thanks, just for clarification, this is a backend service so there are no views. Still, I think I'm coming from what you first proposed. So I had distinct tables for Minions and Managers, this worked perfectly. However I would  need to add additional tables for any new employee role, which I would like to avoid. Thus this question, asking on how this could be generalised.

Comment: Or, maybe, just have one PRIVATE navigaton property _employees. Then adding two public getters. I.e.

`public IEnumerable<Employee> Minions => _employees.Where(w => !w.IsManager);` and 
`public IEnumerable<Employee> Managers => _employees.Where(w => w.IsManager);`

Comment: And then you need to keep adding those properties for every role. Again though, try to disconnect your front-end from your data persistence.

Comment: Hm, [Private virtual or abstract members are not allowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0621) :/

Comment: Like I said, stop trying to massage your entities into business objects. That path is fraught with peril!